# Algebra of Algebraically Closed Field that is a field but not finitely generated as a module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I was trying to understand a proof of the Weak Nullstellensatz. In the build-up to the proof it states the following Theorem, without proof.

> If K is an algebraically closed field, then any K-algebra cannot be both a field and finitely generated as a K-module.

I'm not sure why this is true. Can somebody help me understand the proof to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $K\subset L$ is an algebraic field extension, and $K$ is algebraically closed, what can you say?

Comment: If K is an algebraic field extension, we can say that every element of K is a root of some monic polynomial. 

If K is algebraically closed, every polynomial has a root.

Comment: I suggest you to try harder. (Eventually can take a look at [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616565/why-does-an-algebraically-closed-field-not-have-any-non-trivial-algebraic-field), but I won't do this before trying harder.)

Comment: So I've got that if the K-algebra, L, is a field, then we must have K=L. I just need to make the connection to why this means that L cannot be generated as a K-module. If L is finitely generated as an K-module, then it is an integral extension.